# Can a buildSrc task refer to a class in buildSrc?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I'd like to refer to a class that I've defined in `buildSrc/src/main/java` (an enum, but it could also be a task) in `buildSrc/build.gradle`, but I get an `unable to resolve class` error.

Given `buildSrc/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

import SomeEnum

task someTask() {
    def foo = SomeEnum.FOO
    doLast() {
        println("$foo")
    }
}

someTask.dependsOn compileJava
```

and given `src/main/java/SomeEnum.java`:

```
public enum SomeEnum {
    FOO, BAR, BAZ;
}
```

I'd expect that `gradle someTask` would print `FOO`, but instead I get:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file '/u/wk/bwohler/tmp/buildSrcTest/buildSrc/build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file '/u/wk/bwohler/tmp/buildSrcTest/buildSrc/build.gradle': 3: unable to resolve class SomeEnum
   @ line 3, column 1.
     import SomeEnum
     ^
```

Is this possible?

If not, can you suggest a good alternative to allow our buildSrc to use this class? Would the solution be to get rid of buildSrc and use a composite build instead by putting SomeEnum in one included build and our current content of buildSrc in another included build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use a custom class in some Gradle build, you’ll have to build that class in a different build first. In your `buildSrc` build, you’re trying to build the class in the same build in which you’re trying to use it – which isn’t possible.

After having built the class, you’ll want to get it into the second build. For that you’ll have to get it on the build script classpath of that second build. This is usually done via a custom Gradle plugin which contains or depends on the class.

#### Sample Setup

Here’s a sample setup for your use case (tested with Gradle 8.0.2):

```
├── enumProvidingProj
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── settings.gradle
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           ├── groovy
│           │   └── my-enum-convention.gradle
│           └── java
│               └── SomeEnum.java
└── enumUsingProj
    ├── build.gradle
    └── settings.gradle
```

The `enumProvidingProj` builds the `SomeEnum` class and makes it available via a [precompiled script plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.2/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:precompiled_plugins). The `enumUsingProj` then uses the class after it has applied the plugin.  The `enumUsingProj` is hence equivalent to your `buildSrc` build; you can use it as an included build, for example.

Here are the contents of the listed sample files:

##### `enumProvidingProj/build.gradle`

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'groovy-gradle-plugin'
    id 'java'
}
```

##### `enumProvidingProj/settings.gradle`

```groovy
// empty file
```

##### `enumProvidingProj/src/main/groovy/my-enum-convention.gradle`

```groovy
// Empty file is only here to create a plugin.
```

##### `enumProvidingProj/src/main/java/SomeEnum.java`

```java
public enum SomeEnum {
    FOO, BAR, BAZ;
}
```

##### `enumUsingProj/build.gradle`

```groovy
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'my-enum-convention'
}

import SomeEnum

task someTask() {
    def foo = SomeEnum.FOO
    doLast() {
        println("$foo")
    }
}

someTask.dependsOn compileJava
```

##### `enumUsingProj/settings.gradle`

```groovy
pluginManagement {
    includeBuild '../enumProvidingProj'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Chriki. It appears that considering buildSrc for defining stuff and not doing stuff would be a simple way of separating concerns.